# Define the path to the "Bin" folder

Tags: asp.net, web-config, bin

I have an ASP.Net project using AJAX that I am putting on a server behind a reverse proxy.

Lets say my project is located on the server here:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\proj\app

So the bin folder should be here:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\proj\app\Bin

The reverse proxy causes the server to automatically look for the Bin folder for the project here:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bin

because when working behind a reverse proxy all file references need to be relative to the root directory.

I'm assuming that the Bin path is by default set to "~\Bin", which is not relative to the root directory.

I need my Bin folder path to be set to ".\Bin"  Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:

Adding a BIN folder to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bin is NOT an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was a IIS Virtual Directory problem.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use **assemblyBinding** to set the probing patch for your assemblies.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>   
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>   
</configuration>
```

For more information, refer to [assemblyBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e.aspx).

Comment: It seems that you must also add the Assembly and the Namespace at the beginning of every aspx. For example: `<%@ Assembly Name="Foo1" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="FooNamespace" %>` Source: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingTheCodeBehindAssembliesDLLsToADifferentFolderThanBINWithASPNET11.aspx